# If value is in Object javascript

Tags: javascript, object, indexof

**Without using a for** is there a way to determine if an object has a value.

```
var obj = {1: 'j', 54: 1, 29018: 4};
```

I am looking for something like.

```
obj.indexOf('j');
```

I do not really care what the index is just if it's in the object without having nested items.

I am aware I could do, but I am looking for another solution.  As this one is really no better than a for.

```
var array = $.map(obj, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
array.indexOf('j');
```

Comment: `indexOf` isn't a method on Objects, fyi. (It's for Arrays)

Comment: Yes, I am aware.  That's why I said I want something LIKE.

Comment: When you say "without using a for" do you actually mean "without using a **loop**"? Every possible solution for this will involve a loop. JavaScript engines do not keep an index of an object's property values, only property names. So the only way to find out if a *value* is present in the object is to loop over the properties. Of course the loop may be (and should be) encapsulated inside some function - either a function provided by JavaScript or a function you write yourself - but there *will* be a loop in any case.

Comment: why would you not store this data in an array then ? you don't care for the keys anyway right ?

Comment: Michael, I did not know if it could be done, so I was simply finding out if an answer existed.  I posted here because after about 30 minutes of searching I had still come up dry.

Comment: @82Tuskers At this once instance I do not care, in others I am required to have the key.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to loop over object properties and [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if at least one property fulfill condition (ES6 syntax):

```
Object.keys(obj).some(key => obj[key] === 'j'); // true
```

ES5 equivalent:

```
Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) { return obj[key] === 'j' });
```

Comment: Is this not just a for loop?

Comment: @Iscariot No. [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) runs the callback on every item of the array until the callback returns true, in which case it will return true.

Comment: Of course, `Array.prototype.some` does use a `for` loop or equivalent internally. Whatever solution you find for this problem will involve a loop.

Comment: Keys does a for loop just for calling it.  This is actually two loops, and far worse than just doing one.

Comment: @Iscariot I understand what you really mean, but it's slightly confusing to object to a "`for` loop" when there isn't one: a "for loop" is a syntactic construct. (For example, we could avoid using a `for` loop by using a `while` instead.) Instead, you are specifically concerned about the operations taking [O(n) amortized running time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), which means running in "linear time"  (i.e., if the running time scales linearly to the size of the input). You are interested in a solution that runs in sublinear time or constant time.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, you might be able to use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array with the values of an object, and [`[].includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if an array includes some item.

```js
Object.values(obj).includes('j');
```

However, the former is only a proposal, and the later has only been standardized in a draft.

In case you want to check in the same object multiple times, better store the values in a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Unlike arrays, searches are required to be sublinear on average (constant if implemented using a hash).

```
var values = new Set(Object.values(obj));
values.has('j'); // true
values.has('z'); // false
```

Comment: Currently, you can test it on Firefox Nightly.

Comment: And of course, to the OP's requirement of not using a `for` loop, `[].includes` will be implemented internally using a `for` loop or equivalent. You can't get away from the `for` loop for this task, unless you create an index of all the object values first. And how do you create that index? A `for` loop. :-) Either one you write yourself, or one hidden inside whatever library function you use. There will be a for loop in there *somewhere* regardless.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Maybe, maybe not - it's an implementation detail.  It could be that the optimisers get clever enough to realise that your code is constantly asking if there is a property with that value, and starts storing it in some other fashion.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I do not understand the need for your boorish attitude.  Perhaps it helps you in life feel better.  But it's really no necessary.  I am looking for a particular solution, to see if one exists.  It's just a question, there is no need for your behavior.

Comment: @Iscariot: Whoa, I am truly sorry, my friend, I did not mean to come across as boorish or critical. I think it's great that you are investigating this, and I only mean to be helpful in your investigation. So please accept my sincere apology for coming across the wrong way. When I say that every solution for this will involve a `for` loop somewhere or another, I'm not criticizing you for asking! I simply mean that this is how JavaScript engines work - that there will be a loop somewhere, whether you write the loop yourself or whether it's encapsulated inside a library function.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Yes, very true. I'm only talking about the way JavaScript engines work today (to the best of my knowledge). Of course JIT developers are very clever and may come up with other optimizations in the future. And we all owe them thanks for making our JavaScript code faster! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Every possible solution for this problem will involve a `for` loop or equivalent. Even if you use a jQuery function as in one of the examples in your question, or if you use a built-in JavaScript function as in some of the answers, there will be a `for` loop down inside the implementation of those functions.

This is because of the way JavaScript engines represent objects. They typically use a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or equivalent, where the object's property names are the keys into the hash table.

This allows fast lookup of property names without iterating over all the object's properties. But there's no hash table going the other way, where the property *values* are the keys. The only way to find out if a particular value exists in an object is to loop over all the properties - whether you do that yourself with a `for` loop, or whether you call a library function that hides the `for` loop.

Of course, it's a great idea to hide that `for` loop so you don't have to write it out every time. That's what the various library functions do for you. Or, we could go back to first principles and write our own function for this:

```
// Find a value in an object and return the property name that
// contains that value, or null if not found.
function findValue( object, value ) {
    for( var name in object ) {
        if( object.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) {
            if( object[name] === value ) {
                return name;
            }
        }
    }
}

var obj = { a:'abc', d:'def': g:'ghi' };
console.log( findValue( obj, 'def' ) );  // 'd'
console.log( findValue( obj, 'foo' ) );  // null
```

The point is that no matter what library function or other solution you find for this, somewhere under the hood will be a `for` loop very much like the one above.

On the other hand, you don't have to run that `for` loop every time you look up a value! Even if JavaScript engines don't create a reverse index of the the object (where the object *values* are keys into the internal hash table), you can create one yourself.

Here's a way you could do that in any old browser:

```
function ReverseIndex( object ) {
    this.index = {};
    for( var name in object ) {
        if( object.hasOwnProperty(name) ) {
            this.index[ object[name] ] = name;
        }
    }
}

ReverseIndex.prototype.find = function( value ) {
    if( this.index.hasOwnProperty(value) ) {
        return this.index[value];
    }
    return null;
};

var obj = { a:'abc', d:'def', g:'ghi' };
var index = new ReverseIndex( obj );
console.log( index.find( 'def' ) );  // 'd'
console.log( index.find( 'foo' ) );  // null
```

As you can see, there is still a `for` loop involved here, when the `ReverseIndex` is first created. But unlike the first solution, the subsequent calls to `index.find()` do not require any looping. If you will be searching for values inside the object repeatedly, this could be faster than the first solution because it only has to loop over the object once.

You would need a bit more code if additional properties may be added to the object after you create the `ReverseIndex` - but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader at the moment.

And also note that this code assumes that the object values are strings (or convert readily to strings). If the object values are other types, this won't work. See [Oriol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35854098/1202830) for a very clean way to do this lookup using a `set` in modern browsers.

Comment: In case the same object is checked multiple times, it might be faster to create a set (using `for` loop or equivalent) containing the values of the object. This would be the "hash table going the other way".

Comment: @Oriol: Funny you should mention that! I was writing up a second example much like you described (using another object instead of a set, but pretty similar idea) - and saw your comment right after updating the answer. :-)

Comment: The problem of not using a set or map is that the keys of an object can only be strings. So an object will only be reversed properly if all its values are strings.